# $scope variable value not updated in controller Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below added my controller code. I want to access value of $scope.FCGId ....... How can access this variable?

```
 angular.module('hotelApp.controllers')
     .controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope','menu'
         function($scope,'menu') {

             $scope.categories = [];
             $scope.FCGId = 0

             $scope.items = [];

             $scope.getCategories = function() {
                 menu.getCategories().success(function(data) {
                     $scope.categories = data;
                     $scope.FCGId = data['rows'][0].GRPCOD;

                 });
             }

             $scope.getItems = function(gropuId) {
                 menu.getItems(gropuId).success(function(data) {
                     $scope.items = data;
                     console.log(data);
                 });
             }

             $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
                 $scope.getCategories();
                 console.log($scope.FCGId);
                 $scope.getItems($scope.FCGId);

             });
         }
     ]);
```

From, above code returns 0 instead of value updated in getCategories() function.

Comment: Is all this code belongs to same controller?

Comment: yes .. from same controller

Comment: Where do you need to access that? Are you talking about in the HTML?

Comment: Seems to be a timing issue. Are you sure your variable is filled with the result data from your `getCategories()` function when you call your log?

Comment: If you add a console log for `$scope.FCGId` in `getCategories()` and/or `getItems()`, what do you get?

Comment: it's return actual value...

Comment: I'm assuming success is a callback for jQuery AJAX? If so you might prefer to use the angular get/post/put etc.

Comment: Have try `$scope.apply` or `$scope.digest`?

Comment: I am newer in angular so what is solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem happens because javascript almost always runs faster than asynchronous call returns, so your `$scope.getItems` always calls before `$scope.getCategories` returns.

To strictly order the API calls you need a powerful construct called promise. There should be a lot of resources out there, just google "angular promise" and you're good =)

---

**Edit:** Actually making use of the success function is the most straight forward way to do this

```
$scope.getCategories = function() {
    menu.getCategories().success(function(data) {
        $scope.categories = data;
        $scope.FCGId = data['rows'][0].GRPCOD;

        $scope.getItems($scope.FCGId);  // to here
    });
}

$scope.getItems = function(gropuId) {
    menu.getItems(gropuId).success(function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
}

$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
    $scope.getCategories();
    console.log($scope.FCGId);
    // $scope.getItems($scope.FCGId);  // move this line
});
```

By this way you don't have to deal with all those $q and d's. And promise-antipatterns.

Comment: yes using promise it is possible but it is same as we whole function in $scope.on, but i don't want to change structure and want result it is possible?

Comment: slight change to structure

Answer (score 1):

Well

**$scope.getCategories** function is giving asynchronous call
in  below event

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
                 $scope.getCategories();
                 console.log($scope.FCGId);
                 $scope.getItems($scope.FCGId);

             });
```

when you call  **$scope.getCategories()**, this asynchronous call is given.

But script is not waiting for completion of that call. And script access  **$scope.FCGId** variable in **console.log($scope.FCGId);**   without initialization because asynchronous cal is not completed.

Solution to this.

Either you call **$scope.getCategories** function at the start of controller as initialization part
or you should return **promise**  from **$scope.getCategories** function
or use promise in another way as per your requirement.

EDIT CODE.

Defined  **$scope.getCategories** as follow

inejct **$q** in your controller.

```
var defer = $q.defer();       
$scope.getCategories = function() {
                 menu.getCategories().success(function(data) {
                    $scope.categories = data;
                   // $scope.FCGId = data['rows'][0].GRPCOD;
                    defer.resolve(data['rows'][0].GRPCOD);  
                    return defer.promise;

                 });
             }
```

and event handling in this way

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
                 $scope.getCategories().then(function(successData){
                 $scope.FCGId = successData
                  console.log($scope.FCGId);
                 });

                 $scope.getItems($scope.FCGId);

             });
```

Solution -2.
Also there is no dependency while giving call to  **$scope.getCategories** function 
so you can call it at the starting of comptroller.

Same you can do for the call to **$scope.getItems**.

Comment: but it is same as we whole function in $scope.on, but i don't want to change structure and want result it is possible?

Comment: I think defer should be declared inside the function and the promise should be return as soon as the ajax call is fired (aka putting outside of success)

Comment: Yes, @lcycool ,   var defer can be declared outside function and inside this function, we can define this variable defer = $q.defer();

Comment: Can you show me an example of defer declared outside of function?

Comment: var defer ;       
$scope.getCategories = function() {
                 menu.getCategories().success(function(data) {
                    $scope.categories = data;                                                                    defer = $q.defer()
                   // $scope.FCGId = data['rows'][0].GRPCOD;
                    defer.resolve(data['rows'][0].GRPCOD);  
                    return defer.promise;

                 });
             }

Comment: I've made a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/helibufake/2/edit?html,js,output), you can tell me your observation after playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your menu.getCategories() is an asynchronous execution block, and because of deferred execution, you are getting 0 as the value of $scope.FCGId.

You can pass a function as the second parameter to the getCategories function, that will get executed and perform necessary assignments and further calls.

```
$scope.setFCGValue = function(data) {
     $scope.categories = data;
     $scope.FCGId = data['rows'][0].GRPCOD;
     $scope.getItems($scope.FCGId);
};

$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
     menu.getCategories().success($scope.FCGValue);
});
```

What we are doing is passing our custom function, that will be executed after the getCategories() part.

Comment: but it is same as we whole function in $scope.on, but i don't want to change structure and want result it is possible?

Comment: You should then take a look at deferred API of AngularJs $q.